# How to get which textbox was focused before i click the button?

Tags: c#

I want to get which textbox was focused before i click the button.

But when I mousedown on button, the focus will be changed to this button.

So,How can I do???

Or have some event like before click button????

Thanks a lot~~~

Comment: By the way, I don't want to use TextBox.GotFocus to save the TextBox.
Becuse I will create new textbox in runtime.

Comment: You could add a `LostFocus` event handler to your controls and set a private variable `previousFocusedControl` to the event sender each time its fired. That would be a way to keep track of the previous control.

Comment: What problem exactly are you solving? What this button suppose to do?

Comment: You should add whether you are using winforms or wpf.

Comment: Thank you everybody. 
I already found the answer.

Comment: Will it work if they use the keyboard, either by tabbing or pressing an accelerator key?

Comment: Derek,
I don't know,but I think it won't work.
But it's OK~~ We just design for no keyboard. (  Virtual keyboard ).
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can be used in real situation but one tricky way is this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.button1.MouseEnter += button1_MouseEnter;
        }

        void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            focusedTextBox = null;

            if (this.textBox1.Focused)
            {
                focusedTextBox = this.textBox1;
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (focusedTextBox != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(focusedTextBox.Name + " has focuse");
            }
        }

        TextBox focusedTextBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bahrom.
Your idea is match with mine.
After I asked question, I try the way.
But I used foreach to find the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to keep track of when the focus changes for each control you want to track.

[How track when any child control gets or loses the focus in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891423/how-track-when-any-child-control-gets-or-loses-the-focus-in-winforms)

Don't look at only the selected answer, there is an upvoted answer that talks about Enter and Leave events that looks promising.

Here is some sample code that worked for me, you can adjust as needed.

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.textBox1.Leave += Form1_Leave;
     this.textBox2.Leave += Form1_Leave;
     this.textBox3.Leave += Form1_Leave;
  }


  public object LastSender { get; set; }

  private void Form1_Leave( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     LastSender = sender;
  }


  private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
  {
     var lastTextBox = LastSender as TextBox;
     if ( lastTextBox == null ) return;
     MessageBox.Show( lastTextBox.Name );
  }
```

The nice part is that you can subscribe all events to the same method.  So when you dynamically add a new control, you can just do:

```
newTextBox.Leave += Form1_Leave;
```

Comment: Thank you, Derek.
But I don't want to set any events in textbox to record.